# Rest API design with Spring Boot

Tags: rest, spring

In a recruitment interview I got this small projet to do at home: rest API written in Java using Spring Boot. As I didn't hear back from the company I wanted to have feedback from review.
I am a rest api/spring boot beginner.

Requirements: Design a rest API managing horse races and their particpants:

- A race hase a name, date and unique number for that date
- A race has at least 3 participants
- A particpant has a name and an unique id
- The participant in a race have consecutive ids starting with 1

The API must expose methods for:

- Create races
- Create their participants
- Persist both in a sql db
- Add Kafka producer/consumer layer so that the races could be read from systems outside ( As I've never used Kafka, I didn't do that part)

Here is my code, following Controller -> Service -> Repository pattern:

- Domain

```
/***RACE***/

public interface IRace {

    int MIN_COURSE_SIZE = 3;

    String getName();
    LocalDate getDate();
    int getDayNumber();
    Set<IRunner> getRunners();
    void addRunner(String name);

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "RACE")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Race implements IRace {

    private AtomicInteger runnersCount = new AtomicInteger(1);

    @EmbeddedId
    @Getter
    RaceId id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "race", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Getter
    private Set<IRunner> runners = new HashSet<>();

    public Race(RaceId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return id.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return id.getDate();
    }

    @Override
    public int getDayNumber() {
        return id.getDayNumber();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<IRunner> getRunners() {
        return runners;
    }

    @Override
    public void addRunner(String name) {
        runners.add(new Runner(name, runnersCount.getAndIncrement(), this));
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id.getName(), id.getDate(), id.getDayNumber());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this)
            return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Race))
            return false;
        Race other = (Race) o;
        return this.id.equals(other.id);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[Race: name=" + getName() + " date=" + getDate() + " dayNumber=" + getDayNumber() + " runners=" + runnersCount;
    }
}



@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RaceId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9092062626878526790L;

    @Column(name = "race_name", nullable = false)
    @Getter
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "race_date", nullable = false)
    @Getter
    private LocalDate date;

    @Column(name="race_day_number",nullable = false)
    @Positive
    @Getter
    private int dayNumber;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, date, dayNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this)
            return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof RaceId))
            return false;
        RaceId other = (RaceId) obj;
        return this.name.equals(other.name) && this.date.equals(other.date) && this.dayNumber == other.dayNumber;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public int getDayNumber() {
        return dayNumber;
    }
}


public class RaceValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidRace, IRace> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidRace constraintAnnotation) {
        ConstraintValidator.super.initialize(constraintAnnotation);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(IRace race, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        if (!isValid(race)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid race");
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Validates following rules:
     * 1. Course runners must be at least n (n = ICourse.MinCourseSize)
     * 2. Runner numbers must be n first integers starting from 1
     * 3. Runners must all be part of the same race
     *
     * @param race
     * @return true if race satisfies the conditions, false otherwise
     */
    private boolean isValid(IRace race) {
        int n = race.getRunners().size();
        if (n <= IRace.MIN_COURSE_SIZE) {
            return false;
        }
        int validSum = (n * (n + 1)) / 2;
        int sum = race.getRunners().stream().mapToInt(r -> r.getNumber()).sum();

        if (sum != validSum) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!race.getRunners().stream().allMatch(r -> r.getCourse().equals(race))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

@Constraint(validatedBy = RaceValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidRace {
    String message() default "Invalid course";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}


/*** RUNNER ***/

public interface IRunner {

    String getName();

    int getNumber();
    void setNumber(int number);

    IRace getCourse();

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "RUNNER")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Runner implements IRunner {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Getter
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    @Getter
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "NUMBER")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private int number;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(
                    name = "race_name",
                    referencedColumnName = "race_name"),
            @JoinColumn(
                    name = "race_date",
                    referencedColumnName = "race_date"),
            @JoinColumn(
                    name = "race_day_number",
                    referencedColumnName = "race_day_number")
    })
    @Getter
    private IRace race;

    public Runner(String name, int number, IRace course) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
        this.race = course;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, number, race);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this)
            return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Runner))
            return false;
        Runner other = (Runner) o;
        return this.name.equals(other.name) && this.number == other.number && this.race.equals(other.race);
    }
}
```

- Repository

```
public interface RaceRepository extends CrudRepository<IRace, RaceId> {

    Iterable<IRace> findByDate(LocalDate date);
    Optional<IRace> findByDateAndDayNumber(LocalDate date, int dayNumber);
}
```

- Service

```
public interface IRaceService {

    IRace save(IRace course);

    Iterable<IRace> findAll();

    Iterable<IRace> findByDate(LocalDate date);

    Optional<IRace> findByDateAndDayNumber(LocalDate date, int dayNumber);
}

@Slf4j
@Service
public class RaceService implements IRaceService {

    @Autowired
    private RaceRepository raceRepository;

    @Override
    public IRace save(IRace race) {
        return raceRepository.save(race);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<IRace> findAll() {
        return raceRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<IRace> findByDate(org.joda.time.LocalDate date) {
        return raceRepository.findByDate(date);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<IRace> findByDateAndDayNumber(LocalDate date, int dayNumber) {
        return raceRepository.findByDateAndDayNumber(date, dayNumber);
    }
}

public class InvalidRaceException extends Exception {
    public InvalidRaceException(String s) {
        super(s);
    }
}
```

- Controller

```
/**
 * Generic wrapper for http response
 */

@Data
@SuperBuilder
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class GenericResponse {

    protected LocalDateTime timeStamp;
    protected HttpStatus httpStatus;
    protected String reason;
    protected String message;
    protected String developerMessage;
    protected Map data;

}


import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.CREATED;
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.OK;

@Validated
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/race")
public class RaceController {

    @Autowired
    private IRaceService raceService;

    @GetMapping("/races")
    public ResponseEntity<GenericResponse> findAll() {
        GenericResponse genericResponse = GenericResponse.builder().build();
        genericResponse.timeStamp = LocalDateTime.now();
        genericResponse.data = Map.of("races", raceService.findAll());
        genericResponse.message = "races found";
        genericResponse.httpStatus = OK;
        return ResponseEntity.ok(genericResponse);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/race/{date}")
    public ResponseEntity<GenericResponse> findByDate(@PathVariable("date") LocalDate date) {
        GenericResponse genericResponse = GenericResponse.builder().build();
        genericResponse.timeStamp = LocalDateTime.now();
        genericResponse.data = Map.of("races", raceService.findByDate(date));
        genericResponse.message = "races found for date: " + date;
        genericResponse.httpStatus = OK;
        return ResponseEntity.ok(genericResponse);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/race", params = {"date", "dayNumber"})
    public ResponseEntity<GenericResponse> findByDateAndDayNumber(@PathVariable("date") LocalDate date, @PathVariable("dayNumber") int dayNumber) {
        GenericResponse genericResponse = GenericResponse.builder().build();
        genericResponse.timeStamp = LocalDateTime.now();
        genericResponse.data = Map.of("races", raceService.findByDateAndDayNumber(date, dayNumber));
        genericResponse.message = "races found";
        genericResponse.httpStatus = OK;
        return ResponseEntity.ok(genericResponse);
    }

    @PostMapping("/race")
    public ResponseEntity<GenericResponse> addRace(@RequestBody @ValidRace IRace race) {
        GenericResponse genericResponse = GenericResponse.builder().build();
        genericResponse.timeStamp = LocalDateTime.now();
        genericResponse.data = Map.of("races", raceService.save(race));
        genericResponse.message = "race created";
        genericResponse.httpStatus = CREATED;
        return ResponseEntity.ok(genericResponse);
    }

    @PostMapping("/race/{runnerName}")
    public ResponseEntity<GenericResponse> addRunner(@RequestBody @ValidRace IRace race, @PathVariable String runnerName) {
        race.addRunner(runnerName);
        GenericResponse genericResponse = GenericResponse.builder().build();
        genericResponse.timeStamp = LocalDateTime.now();
        genericResponse.data = Map.of("races", raceService.save(race));
        genericResponse.message = "race created";
        genericResponse.httpStatus = CREATED;
        return ResponseEntity.ok(genericResponse);
    }

}
```

Any critics are welcomed.
Thank you very much

Comment: Why havent you concidered to use data-rest? (https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-rest)

Answer (score 1):

```
@GetMapping("/races")
public ResponseEntity<GenericResponse> findAll() {
    GenericResponse genericResponse = GenericResponse.builder().build();
    genericResponse.timeStamp = LocalDateTime.now();
    genericResponse.data = Map.of("races", raceService.findAll());
    genericResponse.message = "races found";
    genericResponse.httpStatus = OK;
    return ResponseEntity.ok(genericResponse);
}
```

findAll seems a problematic If you have a lot of data. you will encounter a lot of heap, and maybe HEAP OVERFLOW.
what I will suggest is to use paging, or any other technique that prevent loading all the data in this way. there is a bunch of technique that you can use.

```
findByDate(org.joda.time.LocalDate date)
```

once you imported LocalDate, why to put the full path into method parameter ?

`throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid race");`

better to add the id of the race or any thing that indicate to the info for investigation logs.